# Create a predictor from an endpoint in a different region

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have created an endpoint on us-east-1. try to create a predictor:

```
In [106]: sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor(<endpoint name>)
```

and get

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeEndpoint operation: 
Could not find endpoint "arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:<account number>:endpoint/<endpoint name>".
```

which is perfectly correct, since the endpoint is on us-east-1.  Probably I could change some defaults, but I'd rather not - I work on us-east-2 99% of the time.

So, how can I set a different region when initializing the predictor?

Comment: Which Sagemaker SDK are you using? Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (python) `Predictors` [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/predictors.html) shows that you can pass a `Session` object. In turn, the `Session` can be [initialized](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/session.html#sagemaker.session.Session) with a *client* and a *runtime client* - the former does everything except endpoint invocations, the latter does... endpoint invocations.

Those clients are tied to specific regions. It seems like you should be able to set the runtime client region to match your endpoint, by manually instantiating it, while leaving the regular client alone (disclaimer here: I haven't tried this - if you do, let me/us know how it goes :)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify the region when you create the client, like so:

`sm_runtime = boto3.client(service_name='sagemaker-runtime', region_name='us-east-1')`